# How to automatically report an SQL query into an Excel spreadsheet in regular intervals

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, excel

I am currently working on an application that is meant to be relaying realtime data on screens. I would like to know how to automatically report the resultset of a SQL query to a Microsoft excel sheet using SQL Server 2005.

Many thanks for your audience and anticipated help.

Cheers,
Tunde

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest way of exporting from SQL Server to Excel in TSQL with OPENROWSET.  [Find out more.](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1202)

Then schedule the running of the TSQL using SQL Server Agent.

Comment: Excel is quite happy to open CSVs and I think SQL Server is quite happy to export CSVs

Answer (score 0):

The best would be to write a program Or even a excel Plugin in .net that writes your query result to a csv file at certain intervals that you can open with excel.